# How do I change the z axis for a button in one view controller

Tags: swift, xcode

I am using Xcode/Interface Builder/Swift to build a project. The project has a page view controller that allows the user to swipe left to right. This is the root view controller. On the first view controller that appears, I am placing a button on the bottom right hand corner. The problem is that the page view controller status icon, which is part of the PVC, is in front of the button, which is part of the first view controller.

How do I approach this issue? Does it matter that there are two view controllers involved with this issue?

I tried going to editor -> arrange -> bring to front. But that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by changing button layer position.

button.layer.zPosition = 1;